# Windows Store App ListView flickering / content dispappearing

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps

I have some trouble with `ListView` where the `ItemsSource` can be very important (**over 5'000 items**).

My application is that of a Chat Application consisting of two ListViews.

1. One on the left, the thread ListView showing a list of active thread
   (conversation)
2. One on the right, the conversation ListView showing all messages exchanged.

I am using the `DataTemplate`pattern so that each item of my conversation ListView is customized as follow :
A chat Bubble using `Coding4Fun` package : http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/getting-started-with-the-coding4fun-toolkit-windows-phone-chatbubble-control

Each Chat Bubble has two `TextBlock` (one for the message content, the other for the timestamp).

Later, I intend to add pictures to this messages.

When user clicks on a conversation from the left-panel ListView, the main conversation ListView is loaded with the corresponding conversation (observable) collection.
If that collection is particularly big (in one case, I have more than 10'000 messages), the conversation ListView does show the content, but as soon as a switch to another thread and back to the previous, the content does not show anymore, although it's here, it's loaded. Starting to scroll, makes the ListView flickering and the content, therefore, is visible but severly flickering. If I stop scrolling, no content is showed, showing an empty list.

Further tests showed that this problem occurs only with large collection in concordance of usage of `ScrollIntoView()` method: indeed, I whish to show the bottom of my conversation ListView each time a user clicks on a thread so that he can read the last messages instead of the oldes, therefore saving him to have to scroll all the way to the bottom, each time.

I confirmed this issue by commenting out the line where I make the ListView to scroll to the bottom. The flickering problem is gone.

Finally, as I wrote my question, I found a stackoverflow question that seems to be my case: [Windows Store universal app - ListView oddity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25039561/3535408)

Unfortunately, the solution is not very clear. How can I solve my issue ? How should I use `VirtualizingStackPanel/>`inside a ListView that uses alread `<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>`, `ListView.ItemTemplate>`and `<DataTemplate>` ?

Answer (score 4):

The solution to my flickering problem and how to implement UI Virtualization (normaly introduced in Windows 8.1) as described here https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2216995&seqNum=4 is as follow :

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

To be placed within a `ListView` scope !

`Orientation` must be defined ( `Vertical | Horizontal` ) otherwise a `Critial Failure` occurs !

UI Virtualization enhance large GridViews and ListViews so that huge amount data can be effeciently loaded without slowing down the UI nore blocking it for too long.

Answer (score 0):

Honnestly the answer to your problem would be to redesign your application.

Never should there be so many items in a listview. You need to filter out some results

Example : Sort the question names /types/ etc and only show the corresponding (such as tags in Stack Overflow)

Only show the last lines of the conversation when you load it and allow the user to load more (like facebook's messenger)

Take a look at this [C# listview maximum number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196673/c-sharp-listview-maximum-number-of-rows)

As the answer says. The amount of items in your listview should be limited by common sense. 5k items in one listview is an incredibly high amount for a user to scroll through.

I am assuming your bubbles are in some kind of list or array. You can use Linq to get what you want. Take a look at this [LINQ query to select top five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872946/linq-query-to-select-top-5)

Comment: I agree with your approach. But Windows Store App shows more restriction regarding WPF, because of Virtualization : https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2216995&seqNum=4 . I finally manage to implement it but, the animation is kind of ugly : previous chat bubbles remain a few moments, new bubble come (from newly selected thread), then old chat disappears, like a lag... I am now looking on ScrollIntoView animation... and showing a small number of bubbles per conversation. Any link or guide ?

Comment: I am assuming your bubbles are in some kind of list or array. You can use `Linq` to get what you want. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872946/linq-query-to-select-top-5

Comment: This allows you to pretty much go through your list or arrays the same way you would on an SQL table

Comment: Yes I have an ObsverableCollection<T> conversation in my program. I will look into the LINQ solution. But the problem is, I have hard time to find out to know when a user is scrolling deeper into the conversation, meaning he want to read more than the x last messages. At some point, he will reach the beginning of the ListView. How can I know that so I may have it load the next x previous messages ? Thanks for your quick replies !!

Comment: I am unsure on how to do this but look for "reach bottom of listview" solutions. I think this may help if you have time to investigate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237012/load-more-items-on-grid-view-scroll-end . You could then adapt the code for reaching the top

Comment: Thank you. I managed to use LINQ to select a few messages, but the problem of the animation is still there. Regardless the change of ItemsSource, the ListView scrollbar will remain at the last position (unless ScrollIntoView was used of course). If that position is further than the new loaded conversation count, the animation is nice, really nice. If not, the new conversation can be far off from the most recent message (then the user woud have to scroll!). How can I keep that animation regardless the content of the conversation and even though there is the same amoun of messages ?

Comment: Because messages can differ both in size and content. So two messages can take the whole screen while five small messages will fill the screen. I could keep the ugly animation I have right now, but I think it's a deal breaker for any kind of user.

Comment: Sorry I do not know much as far as animations go maybe start a new question if the problem is not the flickering anymore ?

Comment: Correct, the flickering problem is gone :) You have my thanks !! Il will post the solution below ;)