# Windows Store App - ListView ItemsSource change animation

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, listview, windows-store-apps

After solving my flickering issue here [Windows Store App ListView flickering / content dispappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29845771/3535408) I am facing an animation issue.

To put things in context, I am building a conversation app (chat app) consisting of two `ListViews`.

1. A left-panel to display all currently active threads (list of contacts) ;
2. A right-panel to display the current thread conversation.

As the user clicks on a thread from the left-panel, the corresponding conversation is loaded inside the conversation ListView. Nothing too complicated here.

The problem lies with animations. I'd like to stick with default built-in animations if possible as I am pleased with them and in accordance of Metro UI GuideLines.

Let's assume you have two threads. The first contains a 1000 messages conversation, while the other one, only a 100.
If I click on the first thread (the big one), the conversation loads just fine, with the default animation. Let's assume I scroll all the way to the bottom to read the most recent messages as in any messaging app. If I click now on the smaller thread, the conversation is updated and loaded with the new conversation collection. Default animations occur and, more importantly, NO scrolling required: I am already at the bottom !

If I try to go back to the big thread, I am left somewhere inside the long conversation. Default animations occurs, but I have to scroll all the way to the bottom.

Scrolling to the bottom can be achieved with `ScrollIntoView(item)`. Calling this method right after changing the `ItemsSource` content, breaks the default animation. 
More importantly, the animations are horrible and happen as follow : the old messages remains still, the new ones (from the newly loaded conversation) appear on top of the old ones then the old ones finally disappear. This is just ugly as hell.

How can I set or use the scrollbar so that it stays at the bottom whatsoever, allowing both the ListView to show the last entry AND using the default animation ?

Using a `DispatcherTimer` to produce a slight delay (500ms) before calling ScrollIntoView() allows the default animations to take place (meaning they were still there in fact, but "overwritten" by the scrolling) before the autoscrolling triggers. It's somewhat much better as my previous situation, but still weird. IS there any other way ? Thanks !